# WPF Effects vs Geometry performance

Tags: c#, wpf, rendering

I'm rendering a somewhat complex (200+ DrawingVisuals) 2D map using WPF, and I'm doing some restructuring of my rendering setup.
Before I go and spend a lot of time building a system,  maybe someone has experience here.

I have the option of creating 3-4 copies of each DrawingVisual for each visible state,  for example, a DV for Selected, Hovered, or Normal.
My question is, would it be more performant to just have a single DV and simply apply a shader Effect to it, rather than swapping out the whole drawing visual from the rendering hierarchy.

I don't know the performance cost of Effects vs just using a lot of pre-drawn Geometries and DrawingVisuals.

Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found Drawings being `Freezable` and `Animatable` perform better. To make them have selected, hovering or normal effects use their clones (Freezable.Clone()) to add your effects around them... I think that should perform better.

Comment: Can you clarify a little,  it looks like you're suggesting to Clone, and then also add an Effect to the new Drawing?

Comment: Here's a screenshot that might help show what I'm working with. The black outlines are separate Visuals,  I'm thinking it might be faster simply to apply a shader that colorizes the black border geometry rather than store 3-4 different copies that are pre-rendered to visual.  [link]http://img99.imageshack.us/img99/5355/solutionk.png

Comment: Faster developement or faster performance! :-) ... u decide... I think Drawings are lightweight being freeable and animatable.... but they add code complexity... Visuals are heavier but faster to code.